# Force right colum between two left columns bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot figure out how I can put the orange column between the two black ones in bootstrap 3.
See image for example :)

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

please post code. but you might try putting all three in there own rows sorry best answer I can give with the info given.

```
<div class="row">your column</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 content"></div>
    <aside class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 sidebar"></aside>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 content"></div>
</div>
```

And make your side block floating to right :

```
.container {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.content {
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #3498db;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right; // float to right in small/medium/large devices
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #e74c3c;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
        height: 150px;
    }
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/115786)